# Expressao Regular para validar string provedor do email - Java

Tags: java

Olá!
Estou tentando validar o provedor de um email no Java usando expressão regular, mas não estou conseguindo chegar em um resultado. Declarei a variável para o regex como string, mas a sugestão é usar boolean, só que boolean não atende o que preciso. Eu preciso validar somente o nome do provedor depois do @. Alguém poderia ajudar? Muito obrigada!

```
String email = teste@provedor1.com;
String filter = email.matches("@[a-z0-9]+\\.");
if(filter == "provedor1") {
    System.out.println("Usando o provedor1");  
} else {
    System.out.println("Usando o provedor2");  
}
```

Comment: Sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas  [aqui](/a/340617/112052), [aqui](/a/327150/112052), [aqui](/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).

Answer (score 2):

O importante é começar pela documentação https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/, nesse caso pode-se usar o [`indexOf` (`java.lang.String`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) combinado com o [`substring` (`java.lang.String`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), use o retorno do `indexOf` para validar se a string veio com `@`

Exemplo:

```
String email = "foo@bar.com";
int pos = email.indexOf("@");

if (pos != -1) { // Se retornar -1 é um email invalido
    String provedor = email.substring(pos + 1);

    System.out.println(provedor);
} else {
    System.err.println("Email inválido");
}
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/vEInm8

Ou poderia usar o [`split` (`java.lang.String`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), que internamente usa regex, com o parâmetro de limite para evitar que acaso exista mais de um `@` ele se divida em partes desnecessárias.

Use o

```
String email = "foo@bar.com";
String[] data = email.split("@", 2);

if (data.length > 1) { // se for "1" significa será um email invalido
    String provedor = data[1];

    System.out.println(provedor);
} else {
    System.err.println("Email inválido");
}
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/V3Azlv